# sum : $\large \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\cos(kx)}{2^k}$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

I am trying to find a shorter solution to find the following sum:

> $\large \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\cos(kx)}{2^k}$

Actually  I converted the whole sum : 
$\large \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\cos(kx)}{2^k}$ = Rel $\large \sum_{k=0}^{n}(\frac{e^{ix}}{2})^k$.

I got a too long solution.
Any shorter way to solve it.

Comment: You are doing it  the right way. There is no shortcut. Just sum the geometric series and take the real part.

Comment: What do you mean by too long?

Comment: I means this long expression. : 

$\large 2^{n-1} \frac{  (2-cos(x) (2^{n+1}-cos((n+1)x))  +sin(x)sin( (n+1)x) }{ 5-4cos(x)}$